# How to shift the contents of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need a method that produces the following output for the given input:

Input:

> 4, 5, 1, 6, 2 | 6, 1, 0 | 9, 3, 1, 5, 2, 0, 4, 6, 7, 8

Output:

> 5, 1, 6, 2, 4 | 1, 0, 6 | 3, 1, 5, 2, 0, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9

The program prompts the user to enter multiple arrays of ints, separated by '|'. The program converts the user input from a String to multiple arrays of ints. It has a method that has an array of ints as a parameter. The method moves every element in the array one position to the left; i.e. the value in element 1 is moved to element 0, the value in element 2 is stored in element 1, and so on. Finally, the value in the first element is moved around to the last position.

You must use a for loop to rotate the array. Note that you will need to store the value of element 0 in a temporary variable so that you can later move it into the last element once all the other elements have been moved.

```
//Below is my code so far:

public class IntArrayRotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntArrayRotation prog = new IntArrayRotation();
        prog.start();
    }

    //Begin your code here
    public void start() {
        int[] data = {4, 5, 1, 6, 2};
        int[] result = new int[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result[(i + (data.length - 1)) % data.length] = data[i];
        }

        for (int i : result) {
               System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you need to write some code

Comment: @Reimeus I've posted the codes as well, could you please check where its going wrong

Comment: Looks OK to me.  What goes wrong when you run it?

Comment: This question looks like an assignment.

Comment: Is there any other simple way to solve this without using String Builder?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'm stuck in first part of the question - The program prompts the user to enter multiple arrays of ints, separated by '|'. The program converts the user input from a String to multiple arrays of ints.

Comment: Your question says you want to know how to shift the contents of an array.  You've demonstrated that you know how to shift the contents of the array.  Did you ask the wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter multiple arrays of ints, separated by '|': ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        // Split the input on '|'
        String[] substrs = input.split("\\|");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String substr : substrs) {// Iterate substrs []

            // Split each substr on ','
            String arr[] = substr.split(",");

            // Rotate arr[] as per the requirement
            rotate(arr);

            // String representation of array e.g. [1, 2, 3]
            String str = Arrays.toString(arr);

            // Remove '[' from the string representation of array
            str = str.substring(1);

            // Remove ']' from the string representation of array
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            // Append the remaining part of the string representation of the array along
            // with a '|' at the end
            sb.append(str).append("|");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);// Delete the last '|'
        System.out.println("After rotation: " + sb);
    }

    static void rotate(String[] arr) {
        // Store the first element
        String temp = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Shift all elements starting from index 1 to the left by one place
            arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        }

        // put the first element at the end
        arr[arr.length - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter multiple arrays of ints, separated by '|': 4, 5, 1, 6, 2|6, 1, 0|9, 3, 1, 5, 2, 0, 4, 6, 7, 8
After rotation:  5,  1,  6,  2, 4| 1,  0, 6| 3,  1,  5,  2,  0,  4,  6,  7,  8, 9
```

I have put the required comments in the code so that it will be easier for you to understand. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

**[Update]**

OP: As you have requested, I've posted below the same program without using a `StringBuilder`.  Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter multiple arrays of ints, separated by '|': ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        // Split the input on '|'
        String[] substrs = input.split("\\|");

        String result = "";

        for (String substr : substrs) {// Iterate substrs []

            // Split each substr on ','
            String arr[] = substr.split(",");

            // Rotate arr[] as per the requirement
            rotate(arr);

            // String representation of array e.g. [1, 2, 3]
            String str = Arrays.toString(arr);

            // Remove '[' from the string representation of array
            str = str.substring(1);

            // Remove ']' from the string representation of array
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            // Append the remaining part of the string representation of the array along
            // with a '|' at the end
            result += str + "|";
        }
        result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);// Drop the last '|'
        System.out.println("After rotation: " + result);
    }

    static void rotate(String[] arr) {
        // Store the first element
        String temp = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Shift all elements starting from index 1 to the left by one place
            arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        }

        // put the first element at the end
        arr[arr.length - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how turning stackoverflow.com into domyhomeworkforme.com helps anyone?